# Removing path from Python search module path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I understand that `sys.path` refers to

1. OS paths that have your system libraries. I take it that these refer to `/lib` in *nix or `Windows` on Windows.
2. current directory python started from - I take it if Python is started from `C:\Python`, this would be the current path
3. environmental variable $PYTHONPATH or %PYTHONPATH% - This refers to the path where I can call the Python binary from the command line
4. you can add paths at runtime - Which I understand to be when I run IDLE

I am able to add paths by running the command `sys.path.append` however when I run the command `sys.path.remove` to 'delete' the path I appended, I am unable to do so. Is there a way to do so without having to close IDLE each time?

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu

Comment: It's not clear why you think that you are unable to remove a path from `sys.path`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Everything works as intended on my machine :)

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/home/sergey')
>>> sys.path
['', ..., '/home/sergey']
>>> sys.path.remove('/home/sergey')
>>> sys.path
['', ...]
>>>
```

What exactly have you tried?

Regarding your understanding of things - I'm afraid there are some mis-understandings:

1. `sys.path` is a list of directories which contain *Python modules*, not system libraries. So, simplifying, when you have something like `import blah` in your script, Python interpreter checks those directories one by one to check if there is a file called `blah.py` (or a subdirectory named `blah` with `__init__.py` file inside)
2. Current directory is where *the script* is located, not where Python interpreter is. So if you have `foo.py` and `bar.py` in a directory, you can use `import bar` in `foo.py` and the module will be found because it's in the same directory.
3. $PYTHONPATH is an environment variable which is getting appended to `sys.path` on interpreter startup. So, again, it is related to module search path and has nothing to do with starting Python from command line.
4. Correct, you can modify `sys.path` at runtime - either when running a python script on in IDLE

See [sys.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) and [site](http://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#module-site) for more details.

Comment: I ran the same exact command however it did not work the first time around i.e. I got an error that it could not be removed however after I closed IDLE and re-opened it, ran the command again, it works. Not sure why it didn't work the first time. Also is my understanding of `sys.path` correct?

Comment: This example works in Python IDLE Shell, but doesn't work in a Python Program (the directory is still present when I type `import sys` then `sys.path` in the Python IDLE Shell afterwards. I have to then do `sys.path.remove("example")` in the Python IDLE Shell to remove my example directory. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Edward: the change to sys.path is not permanent and only affects the current process. If you want to make a change system-wide you'll need to have a look inside the site-packages directory and do some changes. See the lnk to the `site` module documentation I linked above

Comment: @Sergey I understand what you are saying. So is `sys.path.append(item)` permanent then and do you know why there is Python support for permanent adding to `sys.path` but no support for permanently removing items from `sys.path`?

Comment: I have discovered that any edits made to `sys.path` in a program are definitely not permanent (when you restart the Python shell they disappear) and are only present in that version of `sys.path` in that program. What **Sergy** said is definitely right.

Answer (score 0):

We can try below to insert, append or remove from sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>>
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/home/log')
>>> sys.path.append('/home/log')
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/log']
>>> sys.path.remove('/home/log')
>>> sys.path
>>> ['']
>>>
```

Answer (score -4):

Use

```
sys.path.append('path/to/file')
```

instead of

```
sys.path.append('path/to/file/')
```

Same with `sys.path.remove()`.