# Manually Delete Python Package Path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I manually removed `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google` through terminal (rm), however it still seems I can import the package in python 2.7.

I am able to run `import google` but when I print `google.__path__` it displays `['/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google']` even though that directory no longer exists because I deleted it.

I initially deleted this package because it was giving me import errors when trying to run google's app engine api, so I need to have `import google` be unlinked to this directory.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the package? I guess the path exists in your sys.path().  Import errors can be generally avoided by using [virtualenv](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app).

Comment: I think in the past I installed it using a script instead of with pip so I don't really know how to go about uninstalling it.  Is there a way to manually remove it from sys.path?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793921/removing-path-from-python-search-module-path) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely) might help you. Btw, does it show any import error when using [virtualenv](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app)?

Comment: Using virtalenv gives me no errors. Thanks! But I still can't seem to remove the package from my path otherwise.  My sys.path includes `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` which is why I'm confused as to why `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/google` still seems to be linked

Comment: `google` comes under `site-packages/`, so it could be linked. Are you able to `cd` into that path from your terminal? Also what is the output by starting python in verbose mode?

Comment: how was the package originally installed?

Comment: @Peter, I guess you are using Linux, which distro?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting python in verbose mode. This will show from where packages are imported. Since the output can overflow, write it to a text file.

```
python -v 2>&1 | tee out.txt 
>>import google
>>exit()
```

Open `out.txt` and see from where google package is being imported.
As suggested earlier, import issues can be avoided by using `virtualenv`.