# Why can modules be imported again after removing their location from sys.path?

Tags: python, import, module, path

My goal is to import a module from a given path, and let my Python program import other modules with the same module name, but imported from different location later on.

I thought I'd do that by changing the system path, but I am facing an issue when removing things from it: it does not look it is really having any effect.

This question may be related to [Removing path from Python search module path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793921/removing-path-from-python-search-module-path), though the question was not really clear there (if related at all) and therefore nor fully answered...

Here is a simple test showing my issue:

First, I created a python module called pttest, in /root

```
:~/bin# cat /root/pttest.py 
pttest="/root/"
```

Then I just show my current working dir (just being elsewhere)

```
:~/bin# pwd
/root/bin
```

Then, I start a Python interpreter, and show the default `sys.path`... all fine...

```
:~/bin# python3
Python 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']
```

From this Python interpreter, I ask for pttest. Since there has been no import, the variable is not found. as expected.

```
>>> pttest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pttest' is not defined
```

Now, I try to import pttest, but since I have never updated the path, it fails: as expected...

```
>>> from pttest import pttest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pttest'
```

Now, I add the include dir into the path and show the modified path:

```
>>> sys.path.append("/root")
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/root']
```

Trying to refer to pttest still does not work since it hasn't yet been imported:

```
>>> pttest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pttest' is not defined
```

I import my module, and now, since the path contains the correct import directory, it is imported successfully:

```
>>> from pttest import pttest
>>> pttest
'/root/'
```

So far so good...
Now I remove the include directory from the system path and show it (clearly showing /root is no longer there):

```
>>> sys.path.remove("/root")
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.10/dist-packages']
```

I also delete the variable my package defined and showing it no longer exists:

```
>>> del pttest
>>> pttest
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pttest' is not defined
```

**Now, the problem:**

I try to re-import my module: since the /root directory which contains this module was removed from the path, I assumed this would not work, but...

```
>>> from pttest import pttest
>>> pttest
'/root/'
```

So it looks indeed that despite the directory being shown as removed from the sytsem path, internally, somewhere it is still there, since the module can still be imported successfully.

That is a problem for me since I need to control where modules (with identical module names) are imported from...

What is the explanation to the above behaviour?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346840/does-python-cache-imported-files

Comment: https://www.pythonmorsels.com/modules-are-cached/ ..  Module is held in cache on sys.modules dict ..

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, it is cached

If you run `sys.path_importer_cache`, it will show you all cached imported paths

Also if you run `sys.modules`, it will show all your imported namespaces.

Comment: So, how can I do to load a module from a given location, do something, and then restore the system to whatever state it was before my load? I.e. can I do tmp=sys.modules['pttest']; sys.modules,['pttest']=None; sys.path.insert(0, <'new_path>); import pttest; do_mythigs(); sys-path.pop(0); sys.modules['hw']=tmp ?
This really feels like a hack... is this the way to do??

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already given answers, I want to clarify to future readers why this works the way it does. See [“the module cache”](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache) to understand Python’s module caching policy.